# Migrate from MySQL to MSSQL as datasource for NHibernate

Tags: mysql, sql-server, nhibernate, migrate

What method/tool would you recommend for migrating from MySQL to MSSQL.

We use NHibernate for mapping objects, so it would be great, if its possible to migrate columns to a compatible state on the MSSQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a mapping over MySQL, simple create a MSSQL db, change the NH configuration to point to it, and export the schema by using `SchemaExport.Execute(...);`

Comment: I've done that. And ended up writing a small piece of code, where I use Massive to copy the rows.